# How to round a number in Firebird?

Tags: sql, casting, rounding, firebird

I have an issue when casting in Firebird

```
with data as (
  select article_name || cast(quantity as varchar(50)) as quantity, PREORDER_ID as PID
  from preorder_item
)

SELECT * FROM DATA
```

Is providing me with

```
| QUANTITY                      | PID                                  |
|-------------------------------|--------------------------------------|
| Mohnbrötchen1.000             | f1cf767c-5218-4ad2-8b92-1105b7690d9a |
| Sesambrötchen1.000            | f1cf767c-5218-4ad2-8b92-1105b7690d9a |
```

Would it be possible to have only 1 or 2 instead of 1.000?

Comment: Name the datatype of "quantity" field. If you want whole numbers, it must be integer. In any case it is better to do data formatting on client side, not on server.

Comment: What would you do if the actual value is for example 1.2 ? still display 1 ?

Answer (score 3):

Try this: ([`round`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref30/firebird-30-language-reference.html#fblangref30-scalarfuncs-round))

```sql
with data as (
  select article_name || cast(round(quantity, 0) as varchar(50)) as quantity, PREORDER_ID as PID
  from preorder_item
)

SELECT * FROM DATA
```

Answer (score 2):

Besides using `ROUND` as suggested by Stéphane Millien, you can also cast `QUANTITY` to `INTEGER`:

```sql
select article_name || cast(quantity as integer) as quantity, PREORDER_ID as PID
from preorder_item
```